# Does Android Studio not recognize anonymous classes?

Tags: java, android, netbeans, android-studio, anonymous-class

When I write the following code in Netbeans (where I was testing out my LightMateConnection class), it compiles and runs without an error.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final LightMateConnection a = new LightMateConnection();
        a.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener()
        {
            @Override
            void onConnect(){
                //Do Stuff
            }
            @Override
            void onDisconnect(){
                //Do Stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since it worked for Netbeans, I figured when I moved over to Android Studio, pretty much the same code would still work. I created the constructor below:

```
public MainActivity(){ //Note that this is a constructor, not a class
    super();

    LightMateConnection lmc = new LightMateConnection();
    lmc.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener()
    {
        @Override
        void onConnect(){
            //Do Stuff
        }
        @Override
        void onDisconnect(){
            //Do Stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Android Studio gives me 3 errors. On line 4, where there is `...(new ConnectionListener()`, I get "Class 'Anonymous class derived from ConnectionListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onConnect()' in 'ConnectionListener'". Obviously I'm implementing those methods right below it, and Netbeans was able to catch on. My other two errors are on the Override annotations, and they are "Method does not override method from its superclass".

It's like Android Studio isn't interpreting my code the same way that Netbeans did.

Comment: Is Android Studio importing the `ConnectionListener` from the correct package?

Comment: Yeah, It's my own `ConnectionListener`:
`import com.coolkev.lightmate.ConnectionListener;`

Comment: Try restarting, may be some AS' glitch, happens sometimes

Comment: I restarted AS, then ran Build -> Clean, still had errors, and then I ran Build -> Build anyways, and still had errors during the Gradle build

Comment: In your `ConnectionListener` package, is `onConnect()` public?  If so, make it public when you override it. Java doesn't allow you to make overriding methods less accessible, and I don't think the rules are any different for anonymous classes.

Comment: If ConnectionListener is an interface, its methods are `public` by default (actually _always_ `public`--you can't make them anything else).  So you have to make them public when you override.

Comment: Yeah, it was related to the permissiveness of the class, not the IDE. I forgot that the package changed when I moved to AS, and that would have an effect on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being related to the fact that when I moved the code over to Android Studio, the package changed, and all of a sudden I couldn't implement non-public methods.

That explains why I was getting the methods not overwritten error, because the default-visibility methods weren't being overwritten because they weren't visible by my out of package code.

My solution to the problem was to make the methods of ConnectionListener public, so they could be accessed out of package.